# Django API fronted by Azure API gateway

Tags: django, jwt, openid-connect, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I have a Django application that currently stores user credentials and performs authorization and authentication. I am in the process of breaking off the front-end into an Angular SPA and converting the backend to a REST API. My Django API will live as an Azure API app protected by Azure API Gateway. I would like to remove the authentication piece from Django and allow users to sign in using OpenID Connect through either Google or Microsoft Account. What I would like to happen is this:

When a user visits the site, assuming they have never registered with my app, they will have the option to sign in with their Google account or Microsoft Account. If the user decides to sign in using their Google or Microsoft account, (this is where I'm confused and why i'm posting here ... ) I *think* what happens is the API Gateway performs the authentication, generates a JSON Web Token (JWT), and sends that token back to the Django API. Django receives the JWT, decrypts it, and checks to see if there is a user account matching the email address in the JWT. If there is not a user account, Django will add a user to the user accounts table (not storing a password). If there is a user matching that email address, then Django allows the user in.

All that said, I guess my question(s) are:

1. Should I do the authentication at the API Management Gateway or should I do it at the Azure Web API?
2. Can I use Django's built-in authentication system to do what I want or is that not needed?
3. Am I over-complicating all of this? Is there an easier way to do this? All this seems like a lot of work.
4. Is OpenID Connect what I should be using (instead of Oauth2)? I have no experience with either.

Answer (score 2):

Azure API Management does not actually provide any kind of JWT issuing mechanism, so you'll have to implement that yourself. The end points for doing that may or may not be exposed via API management.

What possibly gets you confused is the fact that the APIm **Portal** supports various indentity providers, like Twitter or Google, to sign up for the API. But these are **not** your application users, these are for the **API Portal Users**.

What you **can** do with the APIm Gateway is to validate subsequent calls to your backend API that the supplied JWT token is valid (using the `<validate-jwt>` policy).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, if I am understanding correctly, API Gateway is not an oAuth2 provider and will not issue tokens? That said, do you know if the authentication provider built into Azure API Apps can provide a token?

Comment: Hello Progger, yes, you're right, the APIm Gateway does not act as an OAuth2 Provider. I have not yet worked with the API Apps, so unfortunately, I can't answer that question.